# Add case insensitive collation to PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, collation

By default, PostgreSQL comes without case insensitive collations. Its documentation describes a way to add new collations based on OS locales, e.g.:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createcollation.html

however the created collations are case sensitive.

My question is: **How to add a case INsensitive collation to a PostgreSQL server ?**

Can somebody describe a workflow ?

I was not able to find any references on the net, while some people mention that it is possible.
I've tested with v9.1 - Debian GNU/Linux and v9.2 on Windows.

Just to clarify that I'm aware of:

- PostgreSQL **CITEXT** add-on data type
- Usage of **LOWER/UPPER** for searches and indexes.

These are not the solutions that I want.

Comment: Can you give reasons for the solutions you don't want. Maybe there is another way you haven't thought of? I can guess at problems with `lower`/`upper`, but `citext` avoids these: as with a custom collation, it adjusts the meaning of `=` so that the case-insensitivity is transparent to calling code.

Comment: I could not agree more with your question. Need the same thing myself. Did you solve it? If yes, please add your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

"[Nondeterministic collations](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2019/10/14/nondeterministic-collations.html)" were added to Version 12:

> "The most typical use case for nondeterministic collations is probably
>   the case-insensitive comparison. At secondary strength, strings that
>   differ by case compare as equal"

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't seem to be [possible within Postgres iteself](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Case-insensitive-collation-td5740608.html):

> Not from the Postgres project -- we just use the collations supplied by 
>   the operating system.

Comment: I don't care where the collation definition will come from. It might be from the OS, downloaded from the net, etc .. I just want them to be available to the DB.